# read data from text file c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have the following code, where i have a text file stored in a folder(folder2)which is stored in another folder(folder1). My program shows the name of the contents stored in folder2 which is the text file,but I would to be able to read the contents of the text file line by line.How can I do this??
Here is my code:

```
#include <dirent.h> // directory header
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit()
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DIR *pdir = NULL; 
    pdir = opendir ("C:\\folder1\\folder2");
    struct dirent *pent = NULL;

    if (pdir == NULL) 
    {
        cout << "\nERROR! pdir could not be initialised correctly";
        exit (3);
    } // end if

    while (pent = readdir (pdir)) 
    {
        if (pent == NULL) 
        {
           cout << "\nERROR! pent could not be initialised correctly";
            exit (3);
        }
        cout << pent->d_name << endl;
    }
    closedir (pdir);
    cin.get ();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: How could `if (pent == NULL) ` ever succeed?

Comment: @NeilButterworth  if(pent==NULL) means if pent has not been initialized an error message is displayed

Comment: But `while (pent = readdir (pdir)) `   means the loop will never be entered if `pent` is `NULL`.

Comment: I don't really quite get your argument but what do you think I should write instead??@NeilButterworth

Comment: All this code is just to find the filename.  Once you have the filename, you could, as one option, open it in a separate function with ifstream and read lines with std::ifstream::getline.  There will be plenty of code if you search for those.